# Getting actual facebook and twitter image urls using python

Tags: python, facebook, image, python-2.7, urllib2

I want to write a python code that downloads 'main' image from urls that contain images.

I have urls like these in my data (text files)

1. http://t.co/fd9F0Gp1P1

points to an fb image

1. http://t.co/0Ldy6j26fb

points to twitter image

but their expanded urls don't result in .jpg,.png images. Instead they direct us to a page that contains the desired image.

How do I download images from these urls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you will find an example of how I downloaded the plane image from the facebook page, you can adapt this to work for your twitter page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

urlData = urllib.urlopen('https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10152055005350906')
data = str(urlData.readlines())
bs = BeautifulSoup(data)
imgUrl = bs.find('img', attrs={'class': 'fbPhotoImage img'}).get('src')
urllib.urlretrieve(imgUrl, "plane.jpg")
```

### **EDIT**

I decided to actually help you out with the twitter one as well, here is the twitter example of downloading the image from the link you gave:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

urlData = urllib.urlopen('https://twitter.com/USABillOfRights/status/468852515409502210/photo/1')
data = str(urlData.readlines())
bs = BeautifulSoup(data)
imgUrl = bs.find('img', attrs={'alt': 'Embedded image permalink'}).get('src')
urllib.urlretrieve(imgUrl, "cnn.jpg")
```

And here is the web reference for [BeautifulSoup.](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)