# Getting the URL of an image from twitter PYTHON 3

Tags: python, image, twitter

So I am trying to get the source of an embedded image from Twitter. The URL linking to the image links to a page with the image embedded, so there is nothing I can do to download or otherwise use the image. There was an answer to this question a while ago [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741430/getting-actual-facebook-and-twitter-image-urls-using-python), but the answer provided does not work in python 3, and I'm not quite sure how to convert it. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: So you’re basically asking how to scrape an old mage from the website? What about using the official API that serves links to the current image URLs?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to go to the link and the account was suspended so I can't super test this lol because when I run it I get a none type value from the request but hopefully this gives you something!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import requests

r = requests.get('https://twitter.com/USABillOfRights/status/468852515409502210/photo/1')#, headers = {'HEADERS GO HERE'})
bs = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
imgUrl = bs.find('img', attrs={'alt': 'Embedded image permalink'}).get('src')
urllib.urlretrieve(imgUrl, "cnn.jpg")
```

If the last line doesn't work you can also try this to save the image:

```
with open(...):
     image = requests.get(URL).content
     picture.write(image)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! I tried implementing this into my code but it is reporting the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'` on the line where imgUrl is defined, I believe its the get statement at the end that's causing it but I'm inexperienced with requests so I'm not sure exactly what's wrong.

Comment: I'm fairly new to it as well lol. We get the none type error because the requests.get() isn't actually able to get anything. What did you put in for the headers? I'm fairly certain that it doesn't get anything because the account is suspended and that image is no longer accessible to us but I could be wrong.

Comment: I did some searching and the problem is not with the URL (at least its not only the URL) as I got the same issue using a different URL. I left the headers blank (`r = requests.get(link)`) as I couldn't find anything about what to put there. I looked in the original post I linked and it uses urllib instead of requests so I'm not sure what part (if any) would be the headers of their code. I did some looking into using the twitter API, but that seems kind of overkill for something this simple (not to mention i have to wait for them to verify me).